# Install older version of LAMP in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, php, mysql, lamp

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (I used to have 14.04 LTS and I had to reinstall everything), since I'm still working with PHP 5.6 I must install lamp environment that'll work with that,

Unfortunately, when I use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

it installs PHP 7 and mysql 5.7 which aren't compatible to my project, I tried a few solutions that people suggested here to install php5 alongside with php7 but with no success.

Is there any way to manipulate lamp-server^ installation so it'll install php5.6 as it used to be? I don't need php 7 at all for now.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install php5.6`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAMPP Linux.You can download any version of xampp linux from the below mentioned official xampp site.

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Enter downloaded file location using terminal.

First give certain permission for the downloaded binary file. (Assume that i downloaded 64 bit binary package.)

```
sudo chmod a+x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```

Then install the xampp

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```

If you are download 32 bit binary file do below mentioned like this

```
sudo chmod a+x xampp-linux-5.6.23-0-installer.run 

sudo ./xampp-linux-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```

Xampp sourceforge link below.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/